# Sign an email with "team MyCompany" in Spanish: equipo?

Tags: saludos, email

If in English I would write:

> Kind regards,
>   team RocketNutsCorp

Is this a proper translation in español:

> Saludos cordiales,
>   equipo RocketNutsCorp

Or should I use something with "el personal de..." ?

Comment: _Equipo_ is ok but I don't see it frequently, perhaps is more commonly used _Departamento_ (department).

Comment: In Chile: _Saludos cordiales, Team RocketNutsCorp_. We prefer not translate.

Comment: @Rodrigo why don't you make it an answer?

Comment: It is not a translation, it's just a chilean bad habit. I thoroughly recommend Diego's response.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could certainly use

> equipo RocketNutsCorp

But it would sound to me like you are one of many teams in a competition (Hackathon or the like)

If you say

> **El** equipo de RocketNutsCorp

Then it conveys "all the workers from RocketNutsCorp company"

Additionally, if it fits the nature of "RocketNutsCorp" you could name the department

> El equipo legal de RocketNutsCorp
>
> El equipo de soporte técnico de RocketNutsCorp
>
> RocketNutsCorp, Equipo/Departamento de soporte técnico
>
> FirtName LastName - Departamento de XXX

Answer (score 2):

I'm agree with Diego, but in a regular business email it is not necessary to include the team.

My suggestion is :

```
Saludos cordiales,
RocketNutsCorp
```

That would be clean!

But If corp is not part of the name of RocketNuts, it could be translated like this

```
Saludos cordiales,
Corporación RocketNuts
```

Anyway, I would finally recommend this format:

```
 Saludos cordiales,

 (Title) (Full name) 
 (Email) 
 (Phone) 
 (An image of your company here)
```

Title could:

```
Sr. = Mr.
Sra. = Mrs.
Ing. = Engineer
Presidente ejecutivo = CEO
```